# ValueError while using AutoSlugField and Django-tagging

Tags: python, django, tagging

Am running into ValueError, here is the [full traceback](http://dpaste.com/197332/), the end of which is:

> Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/blog/post/add/
>   Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'treef'

I'm using `AutoSlugField` from [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/).

I am trying to get [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) working, this is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  """Blog post model."""
  title = models.CharField('title', max_length=120)
  slug = AutoSlugField('slug', unique=True, max_length=120, primary_key=True)
  body = models.TextField('body')
  published = models.DateTimeField('publish', default=datetime.now)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
  tags = TagField()

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = ('post')
    verbose_name_plural = ('posts')
    ordering  = ('-published',)
    get_latest_by = 'published'

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is causing your error, but you're missing `populate_from` in your `AutoSlugField` declaration, and I don't think you need `unique=True`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
"""Blog post model."""
title = models.CharField('title', max_length=120)
slug = AutoSlugField('slug', unique=True, max_length=120, primary_key=True)
    ... snip...
```

I think you want:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'title', max_length=120, primary_key=True)
```

Or at least, that's how I use `AutoSlugField` in [some of my code](http://kaleo.dominicrodger.com/browser/cbc/diary/models.py).

I think you're getting your error because django-tagging expects primary keys to be integers, whereas your primary key is going to be a string. Is there a good reason for your `primary_key=True` declaration? Why not just use the default of the automatically added `id` column?

If you're wanting to access your posts using the slug in your URLs (which after all is the point of slugs!), then given this entry in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'post/(?P<slug>.+)/$', single_post)
```

You want a view like this:

```
def single_post(request, slug):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug)
   ...
```

Or you can use [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-detail).

Comment: Yes, this is my URL pattern to reach a single post: url(r'post/(?P<slug>.+)/$', single_post), so I'd like it if if the slug is the primary key, is there no way to work around this?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I will remember to follow this easier to read format further :)

Comment: @user346816 - I've edited my answer to account for your comment. Does that help?

Comment: I used another tagging 3rd party module called django-taggit and I asked on IRC, where they pointed out that in this file http://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/models.py

class TaggedItem(TaggedItemBase):
    object_id = models.IntegerField()

that is the culprit. Is there a way I can work around this? That is I can put in tags = TaggableManager() in my Post model and override the primary key to be taken as as a SlugField?

Comment: @user346816 - you really don't need to make `slug` a primary key - it really doesn't get you anything. There's already a `UNIQUE` index on it. Just use the `id` column as your primary key (the default behaviour) and you're done. I don't think you can do what you're currently doing without changing the internal of the tagging application, which seems like a bad idea, for little gain.

Comment: Yes I saw through the code and modifying the module doesn't leave the application to be pluggable anymore. I changed my Post's model to let Django take care of the Primary key field (default id), it all works great now :) Thank you!

Comment: @user346816 - excellent - if you get a moment, can you mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
slug = AutoSlugField('slug', unique=True, max_length=120, primary_key=True)
```

Your primary key isn't an int.